# Unable to print from Internet Explorer 10

Tags: windows-7, printing, internet-explorer-10

I've recently upgraded a bunch of Windows 7 32bit PCs from IE8 to IE10 using this installer IE10-Windows6.1-x86-en-us.exe. On every PC that I have upgraded IE, the print function has stopped working. No error is being returned. Printing works fine using any other application.
I have tried the Microsoft steps listed at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/973479 and many other troubleshooting steps returned by a Google search but with no success.

How can I restore this function that was working fine in IE8 to IE10 ?

Comment: Issue resolved. Printer driver was out of date.

Answer (score 2):

Issue resolved. Updated printer drive to latest version.